# Android Notification

Tags: android

Как установить время, в которое уведомление будет показано ?

```
public int createInfoNotification(String message, Date when) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_remsmed) //ic_launcher_nuffield
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(message)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT))
            .setWhen(when.getTime())
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    Notification notification = nb.getNotification();
    manager.notify(lastId, notification);
    notifications.put(lastId, notification);
    return lastId++;
}
```

есть такой вот код, я честно думал что уведомление покажется в то время, которое указано методом `setWhen()` у билдера.
Но уведомление почему-то показывается во время выполнения данной функции.

Comment: А вы точно уверены, что вам в метод приходит нужное вам время (с учётом часового пояса), а не текущее?

Comment: Собственно, каково значение `when.getTime()` в момент выполнения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да `Notification` вызывается сразу после вызова `notify()`, в самом `Notification` время лишь информативное поле, чтобы уведомление было вызвано в заданное время, нужно использовать `AlarmManager` и `Service`

```
public class AlarmNotificationService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // здесь вызываем код Notification
        createInfoNotification(message,date);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Задание на уведомление задаем так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(cc, AlarmNotificationService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(cc,intentId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) cc.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

if (intervalInMillis == 0) {
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, datetime, pintent);               
} else {
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, datetime+dateoffset, intervalInMillis, pintent);             
}
```

И не забываем объявить сервис в AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".AlarmNotificationService"></service>
```

Comment: //здесь вызываем код Notification

о каком коде речь?

Comment: Ну который у вас в вопросе написан. Функцию по вызову самого уведомления.

Comment: в рамках этого вопроса, задам еще одни, что такое request code? который мы передаем в метод PendingIntent getService, и что будет если он всегда будет один и тот же ?

Comment: это идентификатор, чтобы потом можно было по нему либо отменить этот интент, либо перезаписать, если я правильно помню.